# Generating a 2D array of integers and splitting it into shapes in c#

Tags: c#, arrays

I am working on a 2D puzzle game (using c#) and I need to generate simple figures from a 2D array of integers.

For example I have generated this array:

```
    [1,1,1,1],
    [1,1,1,1],
    [1,1,1,1],
    [1,1,1,1]
```

And then I need to split it into "shapes". They must not have diagonal connections. For example:

```
        [4,4,4,2],
        [1,1,2,2],
        [1,3,2,3],
        [1,3,3,3]
```

How can I achieve this? The only way I can think of is some kind of pathfinding.
Thank you in advance for answers, I hope that my question is clear.

Comment: Since you haven't imposed any restrictions on the amount of shapes and their area, a valid solution is to draw a single line in between the matrix cells, allowing it to cross itself if needed. Randomly choose a starting point on the matrix edge in between columns/rows, on each step decide whether to step left, right or forward (making only 90 degree turns), stop when you happen to reach the matrix border again.

Comment: I'm not following at all.  You have a 4x4 matrix with a `1` in each cell.  Then you _split it into "shapes"_ and end up with another 4x4 matrix that contains 4 ones, 4 twos, five threes and 3 fours.  What's "shapey" about that second matrix?  What represents the "diagonal connection" that you want to avoid.

Comment: @Flydog57 Cells occupied by the same number form a shape. All parts of that shape connect to each other by side, not by corner.

Comment: @Flydog57, imagine this as something like tetris field. A line of "4" is just a straight line. I need to generate tetris-like figures, but they can be more complex. Each part of the matrix is just a "square" and shapes are made from squares, like in tetris.